# Trying to install adventureworks 2016 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I am a newbie when it comes to sql server, and I am trying to install adventureworks 2016. I clicked on restoring databases, but I cannot find the .bak files, even though I have saved them. Do I need to save the .bak files in a specific place? And then how do I look for them to restore? Thank you!

Thanks everyone for your help! However i am getting this error now when I am restoring the database : 
[ColumnStore Index Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPWZg.png)  even though I have Microsoft Sql Server 2016. How do I fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: The files need to be somewhere that SQL Server has access to.

Comment: `RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
GO`  This will restore the database using the specified file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do that is to copy and paste your .bak file to this path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup

*Note that this path is for my SQL Server 2014 version but just follow this kind of path and you will be in backup folder where you need to paste your .bak file.*

After that in SQL Server Management Studio go with these steps:

1. Right click on **Databases** and then **Restore Database**
2. In Source dialog choose **Device** and click on right button with three dots
3. In **Select backup device** dialog choose **Add**
4. At this point you will see your **Backup** folder with **.bak** files, choose one of them in your case adventureworks 2016 and click **Ok**.
5. Wait couple of seconds to to load/proceed **.bak** file and then confirm with **Ok**
6. If everything is OK after these steps you will see your database restored if it is not there you can refresh **Databases** folder and it will be there.